# Open link in default browser from email client

Tags: javascript, angular, mobile, gmail

I have a web app written on Angular.
Scenario of my issue:

1. I send a link with my app to email and open it from mobile email client in the short version of browser or webview (I don't know how it calls). I've tried click on safari and chrome (even chrome opens in the chrome app still I have that issue)

[image] [image]

2. In the my app I want to login and to confirm my personal number with 3rd party app. 3rd party app I open with `window.open('https://app.bankid.com/?autostarttoken=&redirect=', '_blank')` for iOS and for android `window.open(bankid:///?autostarttoken=)`

[image]

3. After that I go back to email client with my app and my app is empty. - **that is a problem**.

[image]

To fix this issue I can open my app in the default browser from mobile email client, but I've tried difference ways: `window.open(url)` or with `location.href` and I wan't successful.

Could you help me figure out how can I open my app in the default mobile browser or why my app is empty?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I am into this issue right now, Appreciate any help.

Comment: @m I resolved it. I will answer in 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

After a day of investigation. I found out that I had to open link with creating an anchor and click it.

```
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.target = '_blank';
link.href = 'link';
link.setAttribute('visibility', 'hidden');
link.click();
```

or reload a page with
`setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(), 1000);`

I believe it helps somebody.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Do you mind If I can see the exact implementation of this? I've tested on https://test-react-nu.vercel.app/, When I send the link to myself using an email and click it Chrome identify it as popup and immediately block it.

When I tried the `setTimeout()` method it just keeps refreshing on the same email client. I'm on this from days.